# TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'Log_dir'

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, keras, tensorflow, machine-learning-model

I am trying to build model to convert Sign Language to text. I am facing some problem while trying to create and using tensorboard object inorder to visually see the output and optimize my model.

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Activation, Conv2D, Flatten, MaxPooling2D,Dropout
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.utils import normalize
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import TensorBoard
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import pickle
import cv2
import time
# Load the dataset

X = pickle.load(open("X_ab.pickle", "rb"))
Y = pickle.load(open("Y_ab.pickle", "rb"))

modelname = "a-z{}".format(int(time.time()))
board = TensorBoard(Log_dir="logs/{}".format(modelname))

# Scaling the data. /255 since data is image data
X = normalize(X, axis=1)
print("({})".format(X.shape[0]/2400)+str(X.shape))  # (2400,50,50,1) - n,y,x,c


model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), input_shape=X.shape[1:]))  # 64 3,3
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))) #
model.add(Dropout(0.40))
model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3)))  # 5,5
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

# EXTRA
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3)))  # 5,5
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))



# remember to  flatten the data since the data is 2d and dense accepts 1d data
model.add(Flatten())
#model.add(Dense(128)) # 64 to 32

model.add(Dense(26))  # OG 1
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))  # sigmoid


model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

# batch size should be kept a little low(20-200) to avoid negative results

model.fit(X, Y, batch_size=30, epochs=10, validation_split=0.2,callbacks = [board])  # OG 30
model.save("modelname")


i = 6
while i <= 10:
    model.fit(X, Y, batch_size=30, epochs=i, validation_split=0.2,callbacks = [board])  # OG 30
    model.save("{} - ({}).model".format(modelname,i))
    i = i+1
```

The error which I am getting is as follow:

```
python3 model_a-z.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "model_a-z.py", line 16, in <module>
    board = TensorBoard(Log_dir="logs/{}".format(modelname))
    TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'Log_dir'
```

Comment: I've already tried reinstallin protobuf(current version 3.6) tensorflow 1.12.0, tensorboard 12.2.2 and python 3.6

Comment: Keras/TensorBoard is looking for "log_dir" rather than "Log_dir", isn't it?